# What is the best move for Black?

Tags: analysis, middlegame, italian-game

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "25"]

1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Nc6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. Nc3 d6 5. h3 Be7 6. d4 exd4 7. Nxd4 Bd7 8. O-O O-O 9. Bg5 h6 10. Bxf6 Bxf6 11. Nxc6 Bxc6 12. Re1 Re8 13. Qf3
```

What is the best move for Black here, and why?

Comment: Although I have not checked with a computer, I don't see any clear decisive move here for Black. I think this question is more like asking for a strategic plan. Certainly not a puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment, I don't think this is a puzzle because there is no clear decisive tactical sequences.

A good move would be 13...Qe7, putting pressure on the e4 pawn and prepare for ...Bxc3. If White did nothing, Black could then continue with ...Be5 and ...Qf6. Note that it's unlikely a bishop pair can be retained in this position, as White can start the exchange by 14.Nd5 Bxd5.

Answer (score -2):

I could be wrong but b5 seems interesting to me sacrificing a pawn

If he takes with 14.Nxb5 you can follow up with Bxb2 threatening a rook and taking your pawn back, the turn he takes to moves his rook can be used to play a6 kicking the knight back setting up to play Bb5

If he takes with 14.Bxb5 you can exchange with Bxc2, he takes with with pawn then d5, if he starts exchanging hes down a piece because his rook and bishop are misplaced, if he plays 15.Rd1 Qe7 is a perfect move he shouldn't have an answer to

Comment: After 14.Nxb5 Bxb2, f7 is hanging.

Comment: Ahh i see, i tried :(